# JSON data format error

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to fetch data in to a var using a url and do further operation using if and else conditions if the condition is field3==1 it should perform if stt i.e.,we have calculate the time difference between two time stamps using created_at json data values when field3 is 1 otherwise else stt if field3==0.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/"+did+"/feeds.json?api_key="+apikey+"&results=300", function(json1) {
console.log(json1);
json1.feeds.forEach(function(feed,i){
    console.log("\n The details of " + i + "th Object are :  \nCreated_at: " + feed.created_at+ "\nEntry_id:" + feed.entry_id + "\nField1:" + feed.field1 + "\nField2:" + feed.field2+"\nField3:" + feed.field3);      

    var json_data = {created_at:feed.created_at,field3:feed.field3};
    console.log(json_data);
    var feeds = [];
    for(var i in json_data)
    feeds.push(json_data [i]);
    console.log(feeds);
    var powercon = 746 * 0.5;
    console.log(powercon);
    power();
    function power(){
        for (var i=0;i<feeds.length;i++) //feeds should contain the JSON data like mentioned above
        {
            if(feeds[i]["field3"] === "1"){       
            //Start Time
            var d1 = new Date(feeds[i]["created_at"]);
            console.log(d1);
            for (var j=i+1;j<feeds.length;j++) //compare objects starting from 'i' till next "1" is found
            {   
                if(feeds[j]["field3"] === "0")  
                {
                    //End Time
                    var d2 = new Date(feeds[j]["created_at"]);
                    console.log(d2);
                    j=feeds.length;
                }   
            }
            //Time difference in milli seconds
            var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            var diffInSec = diff / 1000; //Convert milliseconds to seconds
            console.log(diffInSec);
            var diffInMin = diff/ 60 / 1000; // Convert milliseconds to minutes
            console.log(diffInMin);
            var diffInHours = diff/ 3600 / 1000; // Convert milliseconds to hours
            console.log(diffInHours);
            var pow = powercon * diffInHours;
            console.log(pow);
            }else{
                 console.log("Field3 is 0");
                 }
            }
        }
```

JsonData is as follows:

```
[{
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:32Z",
        "entry_id": 33358,
        "field1": "4",
        "field2": "4",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:42Z",
        "entry_id": 33357,
        "field1": "4",
        "field2": "4",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T01:00:50Z",
        "entry_id": 33356,
        "field1": "4",
        "field2": "4",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T02:44:08Z",
        "entry_id": 33359,
        "field1": "7",
        "field2": "2",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T02:45:51Z",
        "entry_id": 33360,
        "field1": "1110",
        "field2": "4",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T14:45:36Z",
        "entry_id": 33361,
        "field1": "17",
        "field2": "7",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T14:55:38Z",
        "entry_id": 33362,
        "field1": "17",
        "field2": "7",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:05:39Z",
        "entry_id": 33363,
        "field1": "17",
        "field2": "7",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T15:15:40Z",
        "entry_id": 33364,
        "field1": "17",
        "field2": "7",
        "field3": "0"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:35:52Z",
        "entry_id": 33372,
        "field1": "18",
        "field2": "7",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:41:54Z",
        "entry_id": 33373,
        "field1": "14",
        "field2": "16",
        "field3": "1"
    },
    {
        "created_at": "2017-03-14T16:45:58Z",
        "entry_id": 33374,
        "field1": "9",
        "field2": "21",
        "field3": "1"
    }]
```

The above json data i have to store it in a var feeds and do further process.can anyone help me how to do this??Thankyou.

Comment: What is `Tankvol`? What is purpose of `j=feeds.length`?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I'm not seeing a `feeds` property in your JSON data. Is it failing on `json1.feeds.forEach` perhaps?

Comment: Tankvol is different i forgot to remove it for the above process i dont need tankvol and j=feeds.length is used to check the length @guest271314

Comment: `j` is variable defined within `for` loop. Why assign `j` to value of `feeds.length`?

Comment: the error is the condition if is not processing it is taking else condition for all values if field3==1 @str

Comment: No.I failing at function power() if nn else cond it is taking else if the field3==1@Phil

Comment: we use j=feeds.length to check the process one by one . i have multiple values in created_at json data.the process should be done one by one accepting the condition so we use it.with out that j will assign multiple values to it so we are using that condition for step by step process@guest271314

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2};

temp1 = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(temp1) //"{"a":1,"b":1}"

temp2 = JSON.parse(temp1);
console.log(temp2) //Object {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(temp2.a) //1
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!